# An error occurred while trying to restore packages. Unable to find version 'x.x.xxxx.xxx' of Moq

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am getting an below error while trying to install package 'xxx' on a project through visual studio using manage nuget packages

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages. Unable to find version 'x.x.xxxx.xxx' of Moq. Package 'Moq x.x.xxxx.xxx' is not found on source.

I am getting an this error while trying to install package 'xxx'. Trying to restore failed with the same error
I tried `nuget locals all -clear`
and reopening vs. But nothing worked.

Comment: This is not about any of your packages, this message means Moq (a mocking tool for unit tests) wasn't found in that version. Can you please provide the version it's looking for?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have either not selected the correct package source in the NuGet Package Manager or the source is not configured at all. Make sure that you have `nuget.org` available in the list of package sources. If not, add `nuget.org` with `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` as the path to the list of package sources in Visual Studio and select that. Then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the issue, the problem show that the source doesn't have specific version needed in the source.

This could occurred by the source doesn't have the specific version.

So please add the source which has the specific version.

For example, you could add the official nuget package source:

`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

[image]